# Wordpress images to be shown with col-md-4

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, col

Hi all  I have few images uploaded in **custom post type as featured image** in which  i am trying to connect **bootstrap** with Wordpress and display images side by side in **col-md-4**. but when i do it displays images in new ROW rather than col-md-4

the code is...

```
      <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio_col_image', 'orderby' => 'post_id' ) );
            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>




                            <?php
                            // Must be inside a loop.

                                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                                <div class = "portfolio-column-box">
                                    <div class = "container">

                                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                                       <?php the_post_thumbnail('large', array( 'class'  => 'img-thumbnail'  ) ); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                <?php };
                            ?>

                    </div>
                </div>


                    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe the width of the images is too much. Did you set the image with to 100%?

Comment: you are using bootstrap 3 or boorstrap 4 ?

Comment: @charankumar: i am using bootstrap 4

Comment: @DaBra : I have not set it to 100%

Answer (score 1):

You have loop problem, container should be outside while loop

```
      <div class = "container">
     <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio_col_image', 'orderby' => 'post_id' ) );
        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php
                        // Must be inside a loop.

                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                            <div class = "portfolio-column-box">
                                <div class = "col-md-4">
                                   <?php the_post_thumbnail('large', array( 'class'  => 'img-thumbnail'  ) ); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <?php };
                        ?>

                </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?> 
            </div>
```

the above solution is based on bootstrap 3 version

if you are using bootstrap 4 then you need to include "row" also, as below

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 //your loop here
```

Comment: I tried bot the solution.. but still it shows the images in new row rather than 3 columns

Comment: then you need to check what is the css applied for portfolio-column-box, might be you applied display:block or something

Answer (score 0):

Have u used **row** outside the col-md-4??

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 uses "Flex" for dividing in column so we need to use **row** before using **col**
Previous version of bootstrap used float for **col** so it would work with out **row**.

```
<div class = "portfolio-column-box">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
            $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'post_id' ) );
            while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
                // Must be inside a loop.
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <div class = "col-md-4">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large', array( 'class'  => 'img-thumbnail'  ) ); ?>
                    </div>
               <?php };
            endwhile; ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying **col-md-4** which will show 3 column per row([details](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)), and once have 3 column per row, it should started the new row dynamically and you will have your image in a proper grid. Try below code and see

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio_col_image', 'orderby' => 'post_id' ) );
$i = 0;
?>
<div class="row">;
<?php
while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
?>
        <div class="vc_col-md-4">
            <?php
                //print your image here
            ?>
        </div>
<?php       
    $i++;
    if ($i % 3 == 0) {
?>  
        </div><div class="row">
<?php       
    }       
endwhile;
?>
</div>
```